# How to play next audio track when current ends in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

The code below is supposed to play a single MP3 file, the idea is to skip to a specific part of the track and then start to play from there. Although the cursor moves to the correct position in the mp3, it doesn't play after clicking on Start from the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Song Limit</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div style="margin: 20px; text-align: center;">
        <audio id="myVideo" controls>
        <source src="gpj.mp3" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="gpj.mp3" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </audio>
        <p>
        <b> The Auido Run From Start </b></br>
        <a onclick="setCurTime(0)" href="javascript:void(0)">Start from 0 sec</a>
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
        <b> The Auido Run From Start </b></br>
        <a onclick="setCurTime(20)" href="javascript:void(0)">Start from 20 sec</a>
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
        <b> The Auido Run From Start </b></br>
        <a onclick="setCurTime(35)" href="javascript:void(0)">Start from 35 sec</a>
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
        <b> The Auido Run From Start </b></br>
        <a onclick="setCurTime(47)" href="javascript:void(0)">Start from 47 sec</a>
        </p>
        </div>
        <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        function setCurTime(time_start) {
        vid.currentTime = time_start;
        }
        </script>


        </body>
</HTML>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `vid.play()` after that. as follows

```
function setCurTime(time_start) {
    vid.currentTime = time_start;
    vid.play();
  }
```

P.S remember to set the correct type for your file instead of video/mp4

Answer (score 0):

May be this will solve your problem.

```
 <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
      function setCurTime(time_start) {
      vid.currentTime = time_start;
      vid.play()
    }
```